# Use of #<module-name> while defining a child route for lazy loading in angular

Tags: angular

I am reading an article about lazy loading in Angular.

Can anyone explain to me the purpose of `#LazyModule` in the below route?

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule'}
];
```

The original article: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/how-to-lazy-load-components-in-angular-4-in-three-steps/

Comment: Actually, it is not the word, it is the Class name of that .ts file to be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#<module_name>` is the name of the module's class

```
export class LazyModule{ }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not the word, it is the class name of that `.TS` file to be lazily loaded.

example.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

in `customers.module.ts` `class CustomersModule{}`

So in your case it will be `class LazyModule{}`